# Playframework 2.5.4 sbt less compilation fails

Tags: java, sbt, less, playframework-2.5, webjars

I finally had the time to set up a new play (version 2.5.4) project with the activator using the "play-java" template.
In my build.sbt i added the following line to use bootstrap with less, as described [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AssetsLess#using-less-with-bootstrap).

```
"org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.7"
```

I also created the folder structure as discribed in the documentation

```
app
 |---> assets
           |---> stylesheets
```

There's just a simple **main.less** containing the following lines:

```
@import "lib/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";

body {
  color: aqua;
}
```

Now when I'm calling `activator run`, `activator stage` or `activator dist` everything compiles without an error and on calling **localhost:9000** the bootstrap is included in the **main.css** as expected.

**EDIT:** first i thought the following problem only occurs with heroku but when using `sbt clean compile stage` on my local machine I also get the following error:

```
[info] LESS compiling on 1 source(s)
[error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/app/assets/stylesheets/main.less:1: 'lib/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less' wasn't found. Tried - /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/app/assets/stylesheets/lib/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less,/tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/app/assets/lib/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less,/tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/web/less/main/lib/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less,/tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/public/lib/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less,/tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/web/web-modules/main/webjars/lib/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less,lib/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less
[error] @import "lib/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";     
[error] ^
[error] one error found
[error] (web-assets:less) com.typesafe.sbt.web.CompileProblemsException
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed Aug 10, 2016 2:53:01 PM
!     ERROR: Failed to run sbt!
```

It seems that with sbt the less compilation can't handle the inclusion of the bootstrap.less coming from an external library while compiling. the **activator** works fine.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem, or has an idea what could cause this error?

Comment: What happens when you run `sbt stage` locally instead of `activator stage`?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this problem locally when following your instructions. That would suggest that something is missing. Can you check that all of your code is committed to Git? Maybe Heroku doesn't get something you have locally.

Comment: thank you very much. i will check again if somethings missing and try to also reproduce this locally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally the less files of the bootstrap webjar should be extracted into `target/web/web-modules/main/webjars/lib/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less` during the build.

But the Jar file of the version you are using misses this files:

bootstrap-3.3.7.jar\META-INF\resources\webjars\bootstrap\3.3.7\

`css
fonts
js
webjars-requirejs.js
webjars-requirejs.js.gz`

In the version `3.3.4` the less files are existing.

Comment: i addressed an issue and it has been fixed: https://github.com/webjars/bootstrap/issues/47

Comment: If anybody still has issue with 3.3.7, just use `"org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.7-1"`